# Why assign void to local variable

Tags: swift, syntax

So this is actually possible.

```
func clearItems() {
}

func reloadItems(_ clearItems: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if let void = clearItems?() {

    }
}

reloadItems(clearItems)
```

Should this be illegal? Or should we be forced to use _ intead of a variable name? Can void actually be consumed in some way here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Void is a type in Swift just like anything else. There's seldom need to pass it around, but that doesn't change the fact the language supports returning and storing it in constants.

This implicitly happens anyway, you're just being explicit. You can, if you want `return ()` at the end of every function that doesn't return a value since `()` represents an instance of Void. The compiler does that for you though so you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to change your `reloadItems` method to look like this:

```
func reloadItems(_ clearItems: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if let void = clearItems {
        void() // Call void.
    }
}
```

by saying `clearItems?()`, you are calling the passed function, which is not the thing you wanted to do. You wanted to safely unwrap the passed function, so you need to treat it as a passed variable like the above snippet.

If you didn't use the `if let` statement, you can call `clearItems` like this:

`clearItems?()`

This will call the passed function if it isn't `nil`, and will do nothing if it is `nil`.

So your `reloadItems` function can simply become like this:

```
func reloadItems(_ clearItems: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    clearItems?() // This will call the passed function if it isn't nil, and will do nothing if it is nil.
}
```